# How to eliminate all characters beyond "(" in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

This is my absolute first SQL thingy.

I have a database of song titles. I'm trying to copy those song titles into a field called "Custom" but remove all character after an open parenthesis.

For example:

**Title**

`Stand By Me (Db) - CHART - Drums.pdf`

then becomes

**Custom**

Stand By Me

I used `Update Songs Set Custom = Title`, and it copied all the data from my **Title** column to my **Custom** column but now I want to strip off all the characters after "(".

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: This is going to be SQL dialect specific, please tag your DBMS (MySQL, SQL Server, etc) In a lot of cases SELECT SUBSTR(song_title,INSTR(song_title,'('),LEN(song_title)) will work, but the function names will vary.

Comment: I'm using SQLite Studio. I'm trying to edit my database for my Android app called MobileSheetsPro.

Comment: SQLite Studio is an IDE for SQLite backend? Please can you tag with the actual database software

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend:

```
left(Title , CHARINDEX('(', Title + '(' ) - 1)
```

This works whether or not there is an open paren.  You can use this in either a `SELECT` or `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql server, this will help:

```
Update Songs Set Custom = left(Title , CHARINDEX('(', Title ) -1);
```

If you are using SQLLite go with:

```
Update Songs Set Custom = substr(Title || '(' , 1, instr(Title || '(','(' )-1);
```

I used the recommendation from Gordon in this too by adding '('

Comment: tried that.  got an error of [09:12:51] Error while executing SQL query on database 'mobilesheets': near "(": syntax error

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using SQL Server, you can use following.

```
Update TableName
SET Custom = SUBSTRING(title, 0, CHARINDEX(' (', title))
```

You should get some idea by running below example for reference.

```
DECLARE @Title NVARCHAR(256)
SET @Title = 'Stand By Me (Db) - CHART - Drums.pdf'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Title, 0, CHARINDEX(' (', @Title))
```

Comment: that returned this error [09:15:56] Error while executing SQL query on database 'mobilesheets': no such function: SUBSTRING